# I have four webbrowsers, each named web1, web2, etc... How do I use a for loop for them?

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have a for loop, and four webbrowsers. They are called:

- Web1
- Web2
- Web3
- Web4

I have a for loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
```

I want to write the code once, and have it execute on all four browsers. I thought it was something like this:

```
web[i.toString()]
```

However that outputs:

```
The name "web" does not exist in the current context
```

How would I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array

```
var webBrowsers = new[] { Web1, Web2, Web3, Web4 };

for(int i = 0; i < webBrowsers.Length; i++)
{
    webBrowsers[i]... // Do something with each
}
```

In general, whenever you have variables with serial names (like `Web1`..`Web4`) that's a good indication that you should probably use an array instead. Personally, I'd refactor the code so that you remove all references to the individual `webBrowser` controls, and use an array exclusively. However, that's probably beyond the scope of this question.

**Further Reading:**

- [Arrays Tutorial (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: By the way, wouldn't I use <= instead of < in the for loop? I want it to use all four of them.

Comment: @Minicl55 arrays in C# are base 0, meaning for a 4-element array, the valid indexes are 0, 1, 2, and 3. `webBrowsers.Length` will return 4 (there are 4 elements) but `i` must stop at 3 or you'll get an range exception.

Comment: Aah, I thought it would return 3 instead of 4

Answer (score 1):

You would need to recover the control by name, not statically, but dynamically:

```
var matches = this.Controls.Find(string.Format("Web{0}", i), true);

// this means you can't find that control
if (matches.Length == 0) { continue; }

// now you can cast the first control if you'd like
var web = matches[0] as WebBrowser;
```